# KeyGenerator exception with RC4 algorithm

Tags: java, exception, cryptography

The code is very easy and clear, but it throws exception at

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
```

and

```
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
```

the exception is : 
unreported exception `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;` must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;


public class RCCC4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strDataToEncrypt = new String();
    String strCipherText = new String();
    String strDecryptedText = new String();

    try{ 
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey);
    strDataToEncrypt = "Hello World of Encryption using RC4 ";
    byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt); 
    strCipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
    System.out.println("Cipher Text generated using RC4 is " +strCipherText);
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey,aesCipher.getParameters());
    byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
    strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);
    System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " +strDecryptedText);
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad)
        {
            System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
        }

    catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey)
        {
                System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
        }

    catch (BadPaddingException badPadding)
        {
                System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
        }

    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize)
        {
                System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
        }

    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam)
        {
                System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
        }

}
   }
```

Comment: Well, do you understand *why* the compiler is complaining? It's unlikely that people will just tell you what to do - the idea is that you *learn*.

Comment: Well, you already managed to handle 5 other types of exceptions. So why not handle this one the same way?

Comment: Two notes about the exception handling: if you think you never will get a specific exception, you could throw the non-checked `IllegalStateException` with the previous exception as argument. And all the exceptions thrown are derived from `GeneralSecurityException` which you could also catch, although you really should catch exceptions that depend on the program input (at least `BadPaddingException`) and handle them separately before catching `GeneralSecurityException`.

Answer (score 4):

The code works and is okay as it stands, you just need to add one more catch to catch `NoSuchAlgorithmException` - which won't ever occur in your program.

Because the algorithm name is passed as a String, the method `getInstance()` could possibly throw `NoSuchAlgorithmException` when the name was wrong. It just wouldn't know what to do with an unknown algorithm. This is not your case, but the compiler has to be sure to be happy.

Comment: ...has anyone even tried to compile the program? It is good and sound - the exception isn't thrown, it is reported by compiler as throwable by the `getInstance()` methods.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, with your help the code has successfully worked.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, following [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyGenerator) will tell you that KeyGenerator does support RC4, but specify "ARCFOUR" as algoritm name

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ARCFOUR` instead of `RC4`
[documentation is here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyGenerator)

Comment: @crazyscot OP wants to call `RC4` which is to be specified as `ARCFOUR` so there will be no cause for exception.
I prefer fixing the cause of Exception rather then Handling the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do your homework yourself (please mark the question as such btw.) but here's a hint on the exception:

A `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException` means that the algorithm you want to use (RC4 in your case) is not supported on that machine. That might either be due to a typo (the name might be `rc4` or something else) or the algorithm isn't provided out-of-the-box and you'd have to implement/add it yourself (which I assume is the case here).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to catch this exception as well for it to work out....

```
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you to all of you, with your help the code has successfully worked.

Comment: I've replaced the e.printStackTrace() defaults in my IDE with `throw new IllegalStateException("Exception not correctly handled", e);`, preceded by a comment `// TODO handle exception correctly` which is automatically recognized as a TODO task. Unhandled exceptions should not lead to fall-through (it may lead to compilation problems such as unassigned variables etc).